# Simplify $h(t) = \int_{0}^{1/t}f(u)\times dg^{(n)}\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, stieltjes-integral

I would like to simplify the following Riemann–Stieltjes integral:

$$h(t) = \int_{0}^{1/t}f(u)\times dg^{(n)}\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)$$

with

$$dg^{(n)}\left(\frac{1}{u}\right) = \left(\frac{d^ng(x)}{dx}\right)_{x=1/u}$$

and obtain the equivalent Riemann integral:

$$h(t) = \int_{0}^{1/t}F\left[f(u), g^{(n+1)}\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)\right]\times du$$

My major concern is how to transform the $dg^{(n)}\left(1/u\right)$, assuming that $g$ is continuous. Any reference about practical calculations of the Riemann–Stieltjes integral would also be greatly appreciated as it is not my academic background and such calculations are for engineering purpose.

Comment: Dont confuesd this notation $$\frac{d^ng(x)}{d^nx}$$ and this notation $$\frac{d^ng}{d^nx} (x)$$ there is a huge difference between them? please specifies which one of them you are using

Comment: I just want to calculate the n-th order derivative of $g$ which is a function of $x$ with respect to variable $x$. What is the correct way to write it in your opinion and what in the meaning of the remaining equation?